# Parsing the result of ping using regex with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a python script which generates an output file when pinging a list of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses provided which looks something like the following:

```
Item Number: [item number]

host = [hostname]
PING [IPv4]  
64 bytes from [dst.IP] icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=27.3 ms
64 bytes from [dst.IP] icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=26.8 ms
64 bytes from [dst.IP] icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=21.6 ms
.
.
.
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.604/25.248/27.333/2.589 ms


PING [IPv6] 
64 bytes from [dst.IP] icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=31.3 ms
64 bytes from [dst.IP] icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=22.0 ms
64 bytes from [dst.IP] icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=22.8 ms
.
.
.
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.098/25.480/31.866/4.519 ms

$$$$$
```

Obviously the information within the brackets are variables. My aim is to extract the hostname, ttl and rtt min values for each IP version of each entry which is placed between "Item Number" and "$$$$$ and export it to one row of a csv file for instance.

I am unable to come up with a suitable regular expression to do do this. What I can do so far is only extract all the information for one entry number, meaning all the text between those tags mentioned above:

```
import re

reader = open('file')
text = reader.read()

match_list = re.findall(r'Item Number:\.(.*?)\${5}' ,text, re.S)

length = len(match_list)
for x in match_list:
    print x
```

This code leaves out "Item Number:" and "$$$$$" for each match.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"What I can do so far is only extracting all the information for one entry number"_. Ok, that sounds like a good starting point. Show us your code and we'll work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you first split the file into blocks and then process each block as follows:

```
import csv
import re
from itertools import chain

with open('file') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    text = f_input.read()
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for block in re.findall(r'Item Number:(.*?)\${5}', text, re.S):
        re_hostname =  re.search(r'host = (.*)', block)
        if re_hostname:
            data = re.findall(r'ttl=(\d+) time=([0-9.]+) ', block)
            csv_output.writerow([re_hostname.group(1)] + list(chain.from_iterable(data)))
```

This would result in a csv file as follows:

```
[hostname],57,27.3,57,26.8,57,21.6,61,31.3,61,22.0,61,22.8
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I improved your code for my own application like the following:  
    `data = re.findall(r'ttl=(\d+).*?rtt min\/avg\/max\/mdev = ([0-9.]+)\/', block, re.S)
    csv_output.writerow([re_hostname.group(1)] + list(chain.from_iterable(data)))`

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't quite sure what you needed. If you are happy with the answer, you can click the grey tick to accept the solution.